# Is sorting pairwise distances as hard as sorting arbitrary points?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sorting

If we have $n$ points in $\mathbb{R^d}$, what is the complexity of sorting the $O(n^2)$ pairwise distances?

Clearly the complexity is $\Omega(n^2)$ but is there a reduction to show it is as hard as sorting $n^2$ arbitrarily chosen numbers?

As a concrete sub question, is the complexity $\Theta(n^2\log{n})$ in the comparison model?

Comment: This seems to be open: https://thesai.org/Publications/ViewPaper?Volume=7&Issue=2&Code=IJACSA&SerialNo=78

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an open question even for one-dimensional point sets.  In this setting, the distance-sorting problem is equivalent to [sorting X+Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_%2B_Y_sorting), where $X$ is the input set and $Y=-X$.

Comment: That's very interesting and a little surprising with respect to the comparison model. Thank you.

Comment: http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/TOPP/P41.html is actually very informative. In particular, that the problem *can* be solved with $O(n^2)$ comparisons. However it currently takes $O(n^2 \log n)$ time to work out which comparisons those should be.

Comment: What is the status of this question for points in 2d? Is it know that the problem can be solved in $O(n^2)$ comparisons as in the 1d case?

Comment: I think it can.  Fredman proved that any set of N items from a set of Γ permutations can be sorted using O(N + log Γ) comparisons (by a nonuniform family of decision trees).  In this case, N is the number of distances and Γ is the number of possible distance permutations.  Γ is also the number of full-dimensional cells in an arrangement of N constant-degree algebraic surfaces in R^2n.  It shouldn't be too hard to prove that Γ= N^{O(n)} = 2^{O(n log n)}.

Comment: Thanks. That's  very interesting indeed.